# VRFV2MockCoordinator contract deploy

Tags: chainlink-vrf

```
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")

const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

const VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("30")

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
  const { deploy, log } = deployments
  const deployer = await getNamedAccounts()
  const chainId = network.config.chainId
  let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId

  if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
    const VRFCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract(
      "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock",
      deployer
    )
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address = VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.address

    const transactionResponse = await VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
    const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)
    subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args[0]
    console.log("SubsCription Id: ", subscriptionId)
    await VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(
      subscriptionId,
      VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT
    )
  } else {
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorv2"]
    subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
  }

  const enterenceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["enterenceFee"]
  const gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"]
  const callbackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"]
  const interval = networkConfig[chainId]["interval"]
  const arguments = [
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
    enterenceFee,
    gasLane,
    subscriptionId,
    callbackGasLimit,
    interval,
  ]

  console.log(deployer)

  const lottery = await deploy("Lottery", {
    from: deployer.deployer,
    args: arguments,
    log: true,
    waitConformations: network.config.blockConformations || 1,
  })

  if (
    !developmentChains.includes(network.name) &&
    process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
  ) {
    log("Verifying ..........")
    await verify(lottery.address, args)
  }

  log("--------------------------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "lottery"]
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR processing C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\deploy\01-deploy-lottery.js:
Error: invalid signer or provider (argument="signerOrProvider", value={"deployer":"0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266","player":"0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8"}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:285:21)
    at Contract.BaseContract (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:674:20)
    at new Contract (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:1053:42)
    at getContractAt (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\helpers.ts:437:10)
    at getContractOrNull (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\helpers.ts:464:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3) 
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1222:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3) 
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1052:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:438:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:311:14)
    at Environment.run (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:159:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:584:32)
```

I am not able to figure out what mistake I am making.. also if I am removing deployer address from vrfCoordinatorV2Mock it is giving another error for-- from.toLowerCase() is not defined.
Can someone here help me out with this bug?